# Strong parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I'm getting the error message about strong parameters. I think it's just that rails 4 doesn't use attributes anymore. the code for my toy.rb is:

```
class Toy < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :name, :price, :vendor 
  validates :name, :presence => true 
  validates :price, :presence => true 
  validates :price, :numericality => true 
  validates :vendor, :presence => true 
end
```

how can I change this to strong parameters?

EDIT: I used a different rb i changed it to employees and this is what I have:

```
  class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
params.require(:employee).permit(:first, :last, :salary, :salary, :ssn)
validates  :first, :presence => true
validates  :last, :presence => true
validates  :salary, :presence => true
validates  :salary, :numericality => true
validates  :ssn, :presence => true
```

end

It's still telling me "ndefined local variable or method `params' for #"

Comment: Have you tried googling "rails 4 strong parameters"?

Answer (score 2):

The code you need is

```
params.require(:toy).permit(:name, :price, :vendor)
```

You will put this in your controller. Typically, you create a private method:

```
def create
  Toy.create(toy_params)
end

private
def toy_params
  params.require(:toy).permit(:name, :price, :vendor)
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller for more information.

**Edit**
I think I might have misled you with my original answer. The code goes in the controller, not the model.

Comment: Where do I put that code? Sorry I'm fairly new to this

Comment: Just added a bit more. Do follow the link, as I can't give an exhaustive example in this answer.

Comment: The standard Rails tutorial also covers this subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller

Comment: @fivedigit good call, that's a better resource for someone new to rails. I changed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Strong params are designed to help your **controller** send specific data to your model. It's meant to protect your app against unauthorized data being passed:

```
#app/controllers/toys_controller.rb
Class ToysController < ActiveRecord::Base
    def new
        @toy = Toy.new #-> creates a blank AR object
    end

    def create
        @toy = Toy.new(toys_params) #->creates new AR object (populating with strong params)
        @toy.save
    end 

    private
    def toys_params
        params.require(:toys).permit(:your, :params, :here)
    end 
end
```